# Difference between DBI package and RPostgreSQL packages in R

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I'm building a R package that connects to a PostgreSQL database. I'd like to explicitly state package::function for my functions that depend on external packages. Here is a function from that package:

```
connect_aact <- function(user, password) {

  drv <- DBI::dbDriver('PostgreSQL')
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv,
                   dbname="aact",
                   host="aact-db.ctti-clinicaltrials.org",
                   port=5432,
                   user=user,
                   password=password)

}
```

`dbDriver()` is only from DBI package

`dbConnect()` is from DBI and RPostgreSQL  package

`dbListTables()` is from DBI and RPostgreSQL  package

Question: Do you know if there is any difference between calling `dbConnect()` and `dbListTables()` from `DBI` and calling them from `RPostgreSQL`

Comment: `RPostgreSQL` [depends on `DBI`](https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), which means you cannot have the first work without the second. `DBI` provides a basic interface but can connect to *no* databases. The "drivers" for each DBMS are provided by individual packages, such as `RPostgreSQL`, `RPostgres` (diff implementation), `RSQLite`, `RMySQL`, etc.

Comment: The reason you see some functions written in both packages is that `DBI` provides default implementation that either does nothing or more likely does the basic act; some DBMS deviate from the standard or have more-efficient ways of doing things, so they override the default.

Comment: So in my use, I never load the actual driver package, since I only refer to it when I do `DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), ...)`. I generally *do* use `library(DBI)`, and tend to use those methods.

Comment: That makes so much sense. When I look at the help page for `RPostgreSQL:: dbConnect`, it says `These methods are straight-forward implementations of the corresponding generic functions.`

Comment: Finally, if you look at (for example) `RPostgreSQL`'s implementation of [`dbListTables`](https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/master/R/PostgreSQL.R#L128), you'll see `setMethod("dbListTables", "PostgreSQLConnection",...`, which means that *that* function complements the `DBI`'s implementation, and is called when the connection object (first argument) is of class `PostgreSQLConnection`. Unless you are trying to trick things, you should rarely need to call the specific class-specific version of a function, instead relying on the arguments' signature to trigger the correct version.

Comment: So would you say that writing `DBI::dbConnect()` and `DBI::dbConnect` is fine? It seems like `DBI::` is the more generic implementation.

Comment: Use `DBI` functions, there should be no need to do `library(RPostgreSQL)`. Whether you use `DBI::dbConnect` or `dbConnect` (after `library(DBI)`) is a personal preference, but if you are making a package then I suggest any non-base package should always be referenced verbatim with the `::` notation. There are some packages where this clears up ambiguities (e.g., `dplyr::filter` vs `stats::filter`, `dplyr::lag` vs `stats::lag`), and CRAN checks will complain if you don't do this.

Comment: (Granted, you should not be using `library(...)` in package code anyway. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path)

Comment: Yep. I am not using `library(...)` because Hadley suggests using `::`. Thank you for everything!!!!